# Adding a natural number to a normalized fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science, fractions, rational-numbers

I am currently writing *yet another* rational number class where the fraction should always be normalized. When adding a natural number to a normalized fraction, it possible to get a non-normalized fraction?

In other words, if I compute `r2 := r1 + n` where `r1` is a normalized fraction and `n` a natural number such as:

- `numer(r2) := numer(r1) + n * denom(r1)`
- `denom(r2) := denom(r1)`

With such an algorithm, is it possible to get a fraction `r2` that is not already normalized or will `r2` always be normalized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\dfrac{x}{y}$ be a normalized fraction such as $\gcd(x, y) = 1$. We want to prove that adding an integer to a fraction with the naive algorithm produces another normalized fraction (a fraction for which the greatest common divisor of the numerator and denominator equals $1$). The algorithm produces the following fraction:

$\dfrac{x}{y} + n = \dfrac{x + n·y}{y}$

One of the properties of the greatest common divisor is that for any integer $n$:

$\gcd(a + m·b, b) = \gcd(a, b)$

Therefore, we have the following equivalence for our resulting fraction:

$\gcd(x + n·y, y) = \gcd(x, y) = 1$

Therefore, our algorithm to add an integer to a normalized fraction always produces a normalized fraction.